# How to display multiple questions on single JSP page using radio buttons

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, struts

I'm trying to get the questions from the database and display them to the user for answering. I tried a lot but can't figure it out. The problem is that i get all the questions and radio button with correct values but from the whole page only one radio can be selected ! i.e. from all the 5 questions and 20 radio buttons on the page i'm able to select just one. I want to select one radio button from each question.

```
try{
            Statement st = DBConnection.DBConnection.DBConnect();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            int i = 1;
            while(rs.next()){
                String ques = rs.getString(2);
                String opt1 = rs.getString(3);
                String opt2 = rs.getString(4);
                String opt3 = rs.getString(5);
                String opt4 = rs.getString(6);
                String ans = rs.getString(7);
            %>                
            <%=i%>. <%=ques%><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt1%><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt2%><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt3%><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt4%><br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <%
                i++;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            out.print("Exception Caught"+ex);
        }
```

Also can i check the correct answer against the database using (this part is done at the back end) but how do i do it for each question

```
request.getParameter("ans");
```

and the SQL injections are not a point of concern right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a different name to each radio button set. If your `test` table has a primary key column, that's a good candidate for creating a unique name. This example assumes `rs.getInt(1)` will return the primary key (note the new `int pk = ...` line and the change to the `name=` in the radios):

```
while(rs.next()){
    int pk = rs.getString(1);
    String ques = rs.getString(2);
    String opt1 = rs.getString(3);
    String opt2 = rs.getString(4);
    String opt3 = rs.getString(5);
    String opt4 = rs.getString(6);
    String ans = rs.getString(7);
%>
<%=i%>. <%=ques%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=pk%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt1%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=pk%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt2%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=pk%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt3%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=pk%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt4%><br/>
<br/><br/>
<%
    i++;
}
```

Or you could use the `i` variable if that's easier for you:

```
while(rs.next()){
    String ques = rs.getString(2);
    String opt1 = rs.getString(3);
    String opt2 = rs.getString(4);
    String opt3 = rs.getString(5);
    String opt4 = rs.getString(6);
    String ans = rs.getString(7);
%>
<%=i%>. <%=ques%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt1%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt2%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt3%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt4%><br/>
<br/><br/>
<%
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Since the questions are random using the i value wouldn't get me the correct answer but the primary key worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Ankit, the value of `i` is immaterial. It doesn't matter if questions are in or out of order. The only thing that makes it work is to have the same `name` value for a group of radios that belong together. The value may come from `i`, or `pk` or anything else as long as it changes for every iteration.

Comment: Ankit - glad it worked for you :)  Ravi - I think what Ankit means is that he has to be able to identify the question when the form is posted, and the PK will do that - he can just pull it out of the radio button's name. The `i` can't because it's random and doesn't have any link to the question.

Comment: @EdGibbs I'm stuck again. I can't generate getter and setter methods for these radio buttons in the FormBean. How am i suppose to check them against the DB if i can't get the parameters in the Bean.

Comment: Hi Ankit - sorry but I don't know Java/Struts well enough to help. I'd suggest posting this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set different names(for radio tag) for each group of questions, so they belong to different groups, so you can select several instead of one.

```
    int i = 1;
    while(rs.next()){
        String ques = rs.getString(2);
        String opt1 = rs.getString(3);
        String opt2 = rs.getString(4);
        String opt3 = rs.getString(5);
        String opt4 = rs.getString(6);
        String ans = rs.getString(7);
    %>                
    <%=i%>. <%=ques%><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt1%><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt2%><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt3%><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="ans<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt4%><br/>
    <br/><br/>
    <%
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but its in a while loop. I can't exactly do that.

Answer (score 0):

You've given all your radio buttons the same name `"ans"` and that's why you can select only one from them. You need to group them so that only the options that belong to a particular question have same `name` attribute value. So, you can group them by current question's index for example.

```
<input type="radio" name="ans_<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt1%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans_<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt2%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans_<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt3%><br/>
<input type="radio" name="ans_<%=i%>" value="<%=ans%>"/><%=opt4%><br/>
```